# Spring/Spring bean configuration file option is missing in STS

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite, spring-bean

I am just following a tutorial , where in I need to add a spring configuration file 
but I don't see spring / Spring bean configuration file option in Spring Tool Suite 4 (Version: 4.0.1.RELEASE), could somebody help me where to find that option

[As shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X59xg.png)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to go to Help -> Eclipse marketplace and search and install "Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4.

[image]

Comment: I was also not having Spring bean configuration file option in STS 4. This soution worked for me

Answer (score 10):

You need to go to the Eclipse marketplace under the windows menu and also install the Spring Tool Suite 3. 
Spring Tool Suite 4 mainly has support for Spring boot.

You should be fine after that and see the spring wizard as well when choosing other.

Answer (score 2):

It should be present inside `File > New > Others > Spring` but if not there then you can get it from eclipse marketplace also like below.

1. Help > Eclipse market
2. Type spring and search
3. Find Spring IDE Roo Support and click install
4. Accept terms and click finish
5. Restart STS
6. File > New > Others > Spring > Spring Bean configuration file

Answer (score 1):

**For me using Eclipse Marketplace did not work following the steps suggested by VianneN,**

As I was working with STS 4 IDE from my work PC which is behind an Authenticated Proxy
I ran into following error -

```
SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I fixed it in **three** of simple but time consuming to find out, steps -

**Step 1:**

To fix the certificate issue, I had to generate and copy a new store file 'jssecacerts' with trusted keys of my proxy added to it in Windows Java(JRE path) for the *URL of the plugin* I want to install in eclipse "**download.springsource.com**"

```
C:\Java\Java 8_SE\jre\lib\security\jssecacerts
```

[This reference](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) by **mykong** helped me.

**Step 2:**

Find the complete release URL of the plugin I wanted to install using Eclipse Marketplace
-> Open the Eclipse Marketplace

->  Search for name of plugin or pattern, e.g. "Spring"

->  Click Install for the plugin you want

-> A small window with list of packages should open

-> The first entry should be the URL needed in (grey color)

For me it was - "**https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.11/**"

Try to install, If it fails; go to **Step 3:** and use the URL shown in the first line of the Eclipse Marketplace popup window.

**Step 3:**

I had to use "**Install New Software**" dialog instead of "Eclipse Marketplace" https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.11/ under "Install New Software" -> Paste the URL found in Step 2: under *Work with* and proceed. It worked well for me provided previous two steps were properly done!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem doing an addicional step, not expliained on previous answers:

1. Help > Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search for "spring"
3. Install Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4. After the installation the ide will restart
4. When the ide has restarted, on Package explorer, right click on the project > Maven > Update Project
5. Finally, right click on your project > New > Other > search for "spring bean". The option "Spring Bean Configuration File" should appear

Answer (score 0):

Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4

End of life: This Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4 is no longer maintained or updated. The final and last release is 3.9.22, which corresponds to the Spring Tools 4.14.1 release for Eclipse 2022-03. There will be no updates to newer Spring Tools 4 or newer Eclipse versions anymore. Please upgrade to Spring Tools 4 instead.

Comment: Please provide a resolutions. This suggestion does not fix the problem